# Java stream peek() operation

Tags: java, java-stream

I've been trying to play around with stream operations, and am trying to understand why the following doesn't convert each integer to a string. My understanding of `peek()` is that it acts as an intermediate operator, and applies the given operation to the stream if it is followed by a terminal operator. Any help would be great!

```
List<Integer> testList = Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
testList.stream().peek(x -> x.toString()).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getClass()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peek` performs the operation on each stream element, but does not modify the stream. It is often used to print the elements of a `Stream` before or after some operations for debugging, e.g. `stream.peek(System.out::println)`. The [documentation for `peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) states that it:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.

You are looking for [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), which converts each element of the `Stream` to the result of the function when called with the element. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), it:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

Answer (score 0):

The `peek` operator makes no changes to the stream. It only allows you to look at the items that are flowing through the pipeline in the location where you put it, as if it was a window. You cannot transform the items, or filter them, or otherwise modify the stream - there are other operators for that (such as `map` and `filter`).

You can find a longer discussion on `Stream.peek` here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api

Answer (score 0):

The method peek take a consumer as argument, and consumer just consumes elements it take a value as argument and returns a void, which means that the value returned here `x -> x.toString()` is juste ignored by the JRE, also peek is destinated for debugging, peek means look but don't touch. You want to use map instead.